# error when running ionic application on mac

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I have to perform maintenance on an application made on ionic but when I run the codium it gives me an error

[image]

I'm using a mac to run the application

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Comment: you'll catch flack for using images. This is unlikely related to the Mac and more about the configuration differences between where it **does** work vs. where it **doesn't** work. Validate that first - and don't blindly say they are the same, because they are not.

Comment: what method did you run, 'ionic serve'?

Comment: [Please don't post your code or error as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.